# SQL Server table design handling ubiquitous information

Tags: sql-server, performance, table, best-practices

I have a doubt about table desgin in SQL Server 2019.
Usually i try to map tables with each entity in my "conceptual model", so as usual i do that and create tables for user, articles, customers, orders.. etc.

Then i found that some "entities" in my "conceptual model" are ubiquitous, such entities are translations, images, file documents, textual annotation..etc.

My question is :
which is the best practice to handle such situation? is bettere to have a single table (say tbl_resource) for such "ubiquitous resource" and a cross join table to relate with other "regular entities" or is better to have multiple different tables (one for each kind of resource)?

The former soulution seems easy to implement but maybe i could have some performance penalty.The latter seems to be more rigorous, but i am afraid developing backend will become more complex (i sould handle multiple "ubiquitous resource table" and cross table)
In my scenario i am using SQL Server 2019 standard edition (2 core), and my resource table tend to be "small" (never bigger da 10M rows)

---Edited : Added clarification

When i say ubiquitous i mean that at the moment all the modelled entities (tables) in my model have some information attached, and that information are not homogeneous. I would to factor that information in some way but am not sure if use a single table or multiple tables.

When i talk about file  and image i talk about path, i never store file inisde the DB.

Eg : here an example of what i mean when i talk about ubiquitous information
i have article, brand and category tables (and many more to be fair).
Each entry (record) of those tables may have attached pictures, seo informations, pdfs and translations.

So i have two option IMO :

1. i create a seoTable and a seoCross, a pictureTable and a pictureCross.. and so on.
2. i create a resourceTable and a resourceCross and use that table for such "ubiquitous" information

---Edited : added table example (it's just example, table are for that reason mocked and not complete, i have not specified index or foregin key).
Note : i have translate few name of my actual tables in english, hope to not have messed up the meaning, i use 'reg' for registry and 'res' for resources

Case 1 :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_Customer](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ALIAS] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_Articles](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ARTICLE_NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CATEGORY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_CategoryOfArticles](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

/*Other ~10 tables, all that table have to manage localization in different language, seo element, pictures, and document (mainly pdf)*/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_res_Seo](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LANG] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [META] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_res_Translations](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LANG] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [TEXT] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_res_Files](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LANG] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [PATH] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_res_LinkExternalRes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LANG] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [LINK] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL)

/*Now i can have many cross table for join 
   tbl_reg_Customer <-> tbl_res_Seo
   tbl_reg_Articles <-> tbl_res_Seo
   ...
   ..
   .
   tbl_reg_CategoryOfArticles <-> tbl_res_LinkExternalRes
*/
```

As you can see i have many entities that relate with the same (also many) entities.

Case 1.1 : as the case 1 but instead of many cross table i will follow what suggested by @bbaird (if i well undertood his suggestion) and create only one cross table as follow

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_cross_Resources](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_REGISTRY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REGISTRY_KIND] [int] NOT NULL, /*using convention to identify the source table*/
    [ID_RESOURCE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RESOURCE_KIND] [int] NOT NULL)  /*using convention to identify the resource, target table*/
    /*talbe is all interger so i can easilly apply index*/
```

Case 2 : as the case 1 but without many different table for the resources

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_Customer](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ALIAS] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_Articles](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ARTICLE_NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CATEGORY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_reg_CategoryOfArticles](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SORT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL)

/*Other ~10 tables, all that table have to manage localization in different language, seo element, pictures, and document (mainly pdf)*/

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_res_Resources](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LANG] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [SEO_TITLE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SEO_META] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [SEO_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [TRANSLATION_TEXT] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [PATH] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [LINK] [nvarchar](100) NULL)
 /*If one registry entity has many resource attached e.g. for translation i will leave at null not used field in "duplicate"*/

 /*In that way i have to handle only one cross table*/
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_cross_Resources](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_REGISTRY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REGISTRY_KIND] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_RESOURCE] [int] NOT NULL)
/*talbe is all interger so i can easilly apply index*/
```

In tbl_res_Resources i assume i'll never go in the range of 10M records, that i consider my worst case scenario.
That solution open the door to "duplication", that can occurr when an entity in tbl_reg_Articles for example have many resources attached, for example four text, ten image and three link (but no seo).
In that hypotetical scenario i have 17 resources all related to the same article, i can relate the same resource to many other article using cross table (so is not a real duplication) but i "duplicate" a lot of unused field , the seo field in this example are never used (are set to NULL) in that way i mean "duplicate".

Comment: What do you mean by "ubiquitous"? The word doesn't seem to make much sense to me the way you are using it. And that in turn makes it difficult to understand what you are asking about exactly. Is this about pros and cons of storing different kinds of information – like images, file documents – in the same table vs storing each kind in its own table (images in an image table, file documents in a file document table)?

Comment: @AndriyM yes is about that, i have edited my question adding a more detailed example and context, hope my scenario is much clear now, if not let me know i will integrate.Thanks again for help.

Comment: Deleting my prior answer for now while I try to understand this.  Still not clear exactly what the difference is between 1 and 2.  Also, if you aren't explicitly defining the PK-FK relationships, it makes it difficult to understand exactly how the entities relate (in addition to be a disaster from a data quality standpoint).

Comment: The difference between 1 and 2 is that in 1 resources are separated in many tables. In 2 the resources are placed all in one big sparse table with a discrete number of columns (~20) many of them NULL. So registry tables (reg ones) does not change in both cases, resource tables (res ones) may be splitted (1) or grouped (2) in the same table